# Cannot read length property

Tags: javascript

I just try to search data from 2 dimensional array. for that reason I just run 2 for loop. one for  index & second one is for row index. my first loop is working, but second one condition isn't work.

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  [0, 8, 7, 6, 6]
]
var isFound = false

var find = parseInt(prompt("Enter your number"))

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    if (arr[i][j] == find) {
      console.log("Data is found at index number" + i + ", Row number " + j)
      isFound = true;
      break
    }
  }
}

if (!isFound) {
  console.log("data is not found")
}
```

Comment: A comma is missing at the end of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. The expression is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5][0, 8, 7, 6, 6]`, which is equal to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5][6]` (see [Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)). `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` doesn't have a 7th element, so it returns undefined. (And the outer `[]` make it an array of a single `undefined` value.)

Comment: This is a typo, answer is better as a comment (add the missing comma): `var arr = [ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 8, 7, 6, 6]]`

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems you are taking advantage of the fact that JS auto adds semicolons. That is true. But if you write your elements in two separate lines it will not add commas on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr` is not a two-dimensional array - you've missing a comma between the two "inner" arrays

```js
var arr = [
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    // Here ---^
    [0,8,7,6,6]
]
var isFound = false

var find = parseInt(prompt("Enter your number"))

for( var i =0; i <arr.length; i++) {
    for( var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        if(arr[i][j]==find) {
            console.log("Data is found at index number" + i + ", Row number " + j)
            isFound= true;
            break
        }
    }
}
if (!isFound) {
    console.log("data is not found")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that you're missing a comma between the array values. you must separate values with a comma so that javascript will know that these are two different values within the array:

```
var arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [0, 8, 7, 6, 6]
]
```